# Automatically suspend or hibernate tabs in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Are there any extensions for Firefox that can automatically hibernate or suspend browser tabs (when they haven't been used for a while?) I saw an extension like this a couple of years ago, but I can't remember its name now.

Answer (score 13):

For Firefox >= 59, there is [Auto Tab Discard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-tab-discard).

Comment: That did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla is already working on a fork of [BarTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bartab/) to make this a built-in feature.
[Bugzilla@Mozilla – Bug 675539
Automatically unload (stall/hibernate) longly unused tabs to free RAM](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675539)

Comment: What's the current status? Is it now built-in?

Comment: It is found under `about:config` setting `browser.tabs.unloadOnLowMemory`:
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-or-disable-tab-sleep-feature-in-firefox-browser

Answer (score 1):

Suspend background tabs: https://github.com/KamiIntelligence/Suspend-background-tabs

Suspend tab: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/suspend-tab/

For a summary, you can check this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/36qc63/which_tab_suspender/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is an extension called [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/?src=ss) that does this (by default). It automatically unloads tabs that haven't been used for a while (to free memory), and then allows them to be restored by clicking on them.

Comment: Is there any UI to control this feature? I can't see any in Tab Mix Plus