# How to reduce the Firefox memory usage as much as possible

Tags: firefox, memory, hibernate, firefox-extensions, suspend

I have a small memory and Firefox is using a big chunk of it, I need to reduce its memory usage as much as possible. One possible solution is for Firefox to automatically suspend idle tabs.

First of all, for all solutions in [Automatically suspend or hibernate tabs in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/503261/automatically-suspend-or-hibernate-tabs-in-firefox):

For the ***top*** answer there,

> For Firefox >= 59, there is [Auto Tab Discard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-tab-discard).

That's not what I am after as I don't like my tabs being discarded and disappears. I just want them to be suspended or hibernated, until I revisit them again.

For the ***second*** answer there, found the *"built-in feature"* mentioned in
https://superuser.com/a/504513/203539
at
https://gearupwindows.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-tab-sleep-feature-in-firefox-browser/

Which says:

> To disable the Tab Sleep at any time, double-click on the **browser.tabs.unloadOnLowMemory** preference to set its value to false.
>
> That’s all. Once you have completed the above steps, restart Firefox and it’ll enable/disable the Tab Suspend feature in Firefox based on the value of the preference. If you have set the value to true, *whenever you are working with too many tabs and some tabs are not accessed for some minutes, Firefox will automatically suspend those idle tabs*.

However, when I checked mine, it has been `true` all the time and I had never ever seen any of my tabs been put into sleep mode, even when my system was very low in memory, which triggered me in such treasure hunting.

Besides that, I've also found

**Tab Unloading**
https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/browser/tabunloader/

which says

> You can trigger tab unloading manually by clicking the Unload button in the page.

But look at how my tabs are taking memory now (few hundreds of Megs):

[image]

yet, my Firefox is taking over 2.5G of my memory:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I tried the proposed *"quit & relaunch"* suggestion but found it has some effects but is not fully working as I expected -- my Firefox is still over 1.5G:

> [image]

Whereas I was hoping it can be under 800M, as you can see I've managed to reduce the chrome memory footprint using tab hibernation, and MS Edge is always doing an amazing job limiting its memory footprint. The *only* thing left is my Firefox.

So, how to reduce Firefox's memory usage as much as possible please?

Comment: Set Firefox to restore tabs on startup, then just quit & relaunch it. It will only load the currently open tab, so it will only use as much memory as required for that tab. The more tabs you load, the more it uses.

Comment: Thanks @At0mic, you meant "the more tabs you load, the more you'll save using such practice", right? To be exactly clear, I have many windows, and in each windows I have many tabs, what would it happen exactly when I quit & relaunch it?

Comment: Your Firefox memory usage is *very* high. From my experience, this is not normal. How often are you re-launching the browser, how many extensions do you have? Do you use a third-party anti-virus scanner?

Comment: @xpt no, I mean after restarting, every time you click a tab, it will get loaded, increasing Firefox's total RAM usage. Thus, if you need to conserve memory, you should restart and only click/open/load the tabs you really need. The ones you don't open will remain in your tab list, but they won't get loaded until you click them. For restarting, if you have it set to reopen your tabs, it will still list all your tabs, and it will only load the last tab that was open (currently active tab). In this way, you'll use much less RAM, until you open and load more tabs.

Comment: Thanks for the insights @DanielB. I relaunch the browser only once in a while, and my above 2nd pic is just after its relaunch, and even 1st one too. I only have one single extension which shouldn't take up much memory at all as it is a simplest proxy switcher. This is a corporate PC, but my Firefox is installed myself from the official source. However, all its downloads is being watched by the corporation, apart from virus scanner. I know because I got a warning of my download before -- I was downloading master zip file from github, somehow I got a (wrong) warning about the *its content*.

Comment: Thanks @At0mic for your further explanation. my above 2nd pic is just after its relaunch, without me clicking on any tabs. I have 5 windows in total, which should only contain 5 actives tabs in total as well. However, as we can see from the screenshots, 17 out of 30 tabs are being loaded at start up.

Comment: I may have worded that poorly, so I’ll expand a little: Sometimes, AV scanners inject code into browsers to monitor otherwise encrypted connections. Windows Defender does not do this. So again: Are you using a third-party AV scanner or Windows Defender? // Please also provide a screenshot of `about:processes`. You may want to make the window smaller for that one. // You might want to install an ad-blocking extension like uBlock Origin. Ads often require incredible amounts of resources.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up @DanielB. No, I'm not using any third-party AV scanner but Windows Defender. I've checked `about:processes` and have found nothing out of ordinary. All are the pages I'm on (so I'll not post publicly here). I'll consider uBlock in the future, but for the moment, the biggest memory hog for me are those GDoc pages, which I have to have them unfortunately.

Comment: I just thought about using a 32 bit version of Firefox. A 32 bit application if physically unable to use more than 2^32 bytes = 4GB of RAM. It may be not directly your case because you are talking about 1,5 GB being too high. I'm rather talking about my case when I have 16 GB of RAM without paging file and all they have been used by 2 browsers with Google Street View opened inside.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the resource-sucking madness of modern browsers and web programming.

Literally it says - open less content:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-much-memory-or-cpu-resources

```
Disable resource consuming extensions and themes
Hide intrusive content
Use fewer tabs(!)
Close tabs that use too many system resources(!)
Close other applications(!)
Add RAM to your computer
```

Chrome is not better in memory cosumption.

Comment: +1 For the resource-sucking remark. It might seem banal, but it was actually a design philosophy behind Chrome for a long time: unused RAM is wasted RAM. It's why Chrome has become so notorious for eating RAM for breakfast. I need to dig through my archives to pull up the paper we read for my systems engineering class where Google engineers discuss it, but they conveniently omit discussion of what happens when other applications take the same greedy approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing with the same problem right now, and here's what I've come up with...

Based on resources in the link in [gapsf's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1740604/570055), there are [a couple tools in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-much-memory-or-cpu-resources#w_firefox-tools) that can help manually curtail memory use.

You can use the [Firefox Process Manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/task-manager-tabs-or-extensions-are-slowing-firefox) to triage your efforts.

> To open the Process Manager, click the menu (hamburger) button, click `More Tools` and select `Task Manager` from the menu. The `about:processes` page will open in a new tab.
>
> You can also enter `about:processes` in the address bar or use the keyboard shortcut `Shift + Esc` to open this page.

You can then sort based on memory to help focus efforts:

[image: Screenshot of the first few entries in the Firefox process manager when sorted by descending memory]

This was enough in my case, as I found my extensions were using ~600MB. After removing and disabling a few, I'm down to ~100MB while keeping important extensions like uBlock Origin and Dark Reader enabled. Much to my surprise, Adblock Plus alone was using ~300MB.

You might also have some luck with the **about:memory** page.

> The **about:memory** page allows you to troubleshoot specific issues relating to memory (for instance, caused by a website, an extension, a theme, etc.) and sometimes its `Minimize memory usage` button may help you instantly reduce memory usage. For guidance on use of **about:memory** visit [about:memory](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/performance/memory/about_colon_memory.html).

[image]

Clicking **Show memory reports** > `Measure` (underlined in green) will show a detailed trace of where memory is being used in individual processes. Clicking **Free memory** > `Minimize memory usage` (underlined in magenta) might also be fruitful.

Answer (score -1):

Download the latest https://github.com/lowleveldesign/process-governor and extract the program in to the same place as Firefox's EXE file.

Create a TXT file and place the following inside of it:

```
CD "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox"
procgov64.exe -r --minws=1M --maxws=512M firefox.exe
```

Now save the TXT file and then change the file extension to "bat" without the quotes.

Finally from this point on double click that BAT file (or make a shortcut to it) to launch Firefox with it constrained to 512MB of RAM. Make sure you have not disabled nor severely limited the size of the Page File in Windows to avoid out of memory errors in Firefox.

Edit: The batch file will need to be executed as an Administrator and the memory limit of 512MB will apply to each Firefox process (for me Firefox spawns 12 processes, so that's 12x512MB). Despite running the Batch file as an administrator, Process Governor does not launch Firefox in an elevated state.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Agree with the Community Bot -- have you tried it yourself? what did you get? FTA, in desperate seeking solutions, I gave that a try before, but, my Firefox needs over 1.5G just to start and it'll go over 2.5G very soon. Limiting it to within 512MB of RAM will not even let my Firefox to properly start. Try it yourself before posting any answer please.

Comment: I've added some additional information after having tested it myself.


I've also tested this with the Anno 1800 game. Initially I limited the game to 50MB of RAM and after around 4 to 5 hours of waiting for it to load my Save File it did and the gameplay very slowly initialized at around 1-5 FPS. The game became very playable if I instead limited it to 500MB of RAM.


This method has the fairly obvious downside of increasing Page File usage, which in turn increases storage device utilization & CPU utilization (writing to Page File is costly kernel activity).

Comment: The prospect of executing a batch script containing 3rd party software as administrator every time I start my browser makes the hair on my neck stand on end.