What can I do about excessive use of RAM on Windows 11? Large page consumes 17GB of RAM
I am running Windows 11, and recently my PC became really slow with tearing and lagging on simple things like resizing a window.
When I opened Task Manager I had 27GB used. On further investigation I noticed that large pages are taking up to 17GB of RAM. This is just Firefox open and file explorer in first 20 minutes of computer startup.
This would be okay if I could use RAM normally but I can't. Most VMs cannot be started because I am lacking RAM for them.
Photo of Task Manager.

I am guessing that something is causing memory leak but I don't know how to find that program. If anyone has any suggestions I will gladly accept any help.

Possible duplicate here

See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-much-memory-or-cpu-resources and https://superuser.com/questions/1740578/how-to-reduce-the-firefox-memory-usage-as-much-as-possible . Also consider using https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/Intelligent-standby-list-cleaner-ISLC-v1033-Released, which I find frees up RAM for large tasks.

Very much doubt Firefox is to blame here. To my knowledge, it does not use large pages. Very few programs do. Notable examples are database engines. Got anything like that installed and running?

This question is similar to: Windows using too much RAM, how to diagnose resource hog. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I disagree that this is a duplicate. The issue here is excessive “Large Page” use. All other (especially pool) memory stats are normal.

I do not have any DataBase software running on bare metal all of them are in VM that i can not start because I am missing ram for it. Programs that are active on startup are logitech g app , steam ,wireguar vpn and that is it. I am still trying to find a way to see what is using large pages.
